# Find Length of longest substring with all 1's in a binary string with k queries

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a string of size n consisting of 0s and/or 1s.you have to perform **k** queries and there are **two** types of queries possible.

1. "1"(without quotes): Print length of the longest substring with all '1'.
2. "2 X"(without quotes): where X is an Integer between 1 to n.In this query, you will change character at Xth position to '1' (it is possible that the      character at ith position was already '1')

Input Format:

- First Line of input contains n and k, where n is string length and k is the number of queries.
- Next line contains a string of 0's and/or 1's of length n.
- Each of next k lines contains query of any one type (i.e 1 or 2).

Output Format: For each query of type 1, print in new line the maximum size of subarray 
       with all 1's.

```
     Example Input:                        Example Output:
     5 7                                   0
     00000                                 1
     1                                     1
     2 3                                   3
     1                                     
     2 5
     1
     2 4
     1
```

My Solution: O(k*n) (if most of the queries of type 1)

```
 if(type==1){
        int count=0, ans=0;
        for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++){  //longest len substring
            if(str[i]=='1'){
                count++;
            }else{
               ans=max(ans,count);
               count=0;
            }
        }

        printf("%d\n",ans);
 }else{
        int xth;
        scanf("%d",&xth);
        str[xth-1]='1';   //update
 }
```

I am not able to figure out an efficient solution, as for 'type 1' query only solution I could think of is to iterate through string every time and maintain a "count" variable with all 1's consecutively and finally update "ans" variable when ith str becomes '0'.

I am thinking of using segment tree but don't know how to do. As required good solution should be O(k*log(n)) (doing "type1" query in log(n) time)

Comment: This is a rather neat way to do this excercise.  You should check that `xth - 1` does not exceed the range of your set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using [Disjoint sets datastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), where you start with each number being an empty set.

When a "0" at index `i` is flipped to a "0". check if `item[i-1] == 1`, if so, join the sets `{i}` with the set that contains `i-1`. Similarly to `item[i+1]`.

Since you never disconnect "sets", you can cache the "longest substring" when you calculate the new sets (by checking if the new subset you just created is now longest, and if it does, store the relevant length)

The time complexity of this solution is `O(1)` for "1" type operation, and `O(alpha(n))` for "2" type operation (where `alpha:N->N` is inverse ackerman, which is sublogarithmic).

This gets you total of `O(k*alpha(n))` worst case performance for the `k` queries.

So, for your example:

```
5 7
Create 5 sets: {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}
 00000
 1
Nothing cached, answer is 0
 2 3
2 and 4 are zeros, so don't connect with anything. Cache biggest length 1 ({3})
 1
1 is cached
 2 5
Flip 5. Don't connect with anything.
 1
1 is cached
 2 4
Flip 4. Join({3},{4}) Since both are 1. Join({3,4},{5}) similarly. Cache 3 (since it's the new size of the set contianing 4 is bigger than 1).
 1
3 is cached.
```

Answer (score 0):

absolutely  perfect @amit based on his explanation here is the c++ implementation
Here rank is for maintain max constitutive 1's so you can return Query 1 in O(1) time since SOl will always have the max 1 while updating

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef struct subset
{
    int parent;
    int rank;
}subset;
int find(subset subsets[], int i)
{
    if (subsets[i].parent != i)
        subsets[i].parent = find(subsets, subsets[i].parent);
    return subsets[i].parent;
}
void Union(subset subsets[], int x, int y)
{
    int xroot = find(subsets, x);
    int yroot = find(subsets, y);
    if(subsets[xroot].rank < subsets[yroot].rank)
    {
        subsets[xroot].parent = yroot;
        subsets[yroot].rank += subsets[xroot].rank;
    }
    else if (subsets[xroot].rank > subsets[yroot].rank)
    {
        subsets[yroot].parent = xroot;
        subsets[xroot].rank += subsets[yroot].rank;
    }
    else
    {
        subsets[yroot].parent = xroot;
        subsets[xroot].rank+=subsets[yroot].rank;
    }
}
int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);
    int n,k,i,q,t,sol=0;
    cin >> n >> k;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cin.ignore();
    subset subsets[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        subsets[i].parent = i;
        subsets[i].rank = 0;
        if(s[i]=='1')
        {
            subsets[i].rank = 1;
        }
    }
    for(t=0;t<n;t++)
    {
        if(s[t] == '1' && t!=0 && t!=n-1)
        {
            if(s[t-1] == '1')
            {
                int x = find(subsets,t-1);
                int y = find(subsets,t);
                if(x!=y)
                {

                    Union(subsets,t-1,t);
                    sol = max(sol,max(subsets[x].rank,subsets[y].rank));
                    sol = max(sol,subsets[t].rank);
                }
            }
            if(s[t+1] == '1')
            {
                int x = find(subsets,t+1);
                int y = find(subsets,t);
                if(x!=y)
                {
                    Union(subsets,t+1,t);
                    sol = max(sol,max(subsets[x].rank,subsets[y].rank));
                    sol = max(sol,subsets[t].rank);
                }
            }
        }
        if(s[t] == '1' && t==0 )
        {
            if(s[t+1] == '1')
            {
                int x = find(subsets,t+1);
                int y = find(subsets,t);
                if(x!=y)
                {

                    Union(subsets,t+1,t);
                    sol = max(sol,max(subsets[x].rank,subsets[y].rank));
                    sol = max(sol,subsets[t].rank);
                }
            }
        }
        if(s[t] == '1' && t==n-1)
        {
            if(s[t-1] == '1')
            {
                int x = find(subsets,t-1);
                int y = find(subsets,t);
                if(x!=y)
                {

                    Union(subsets,t-1,t);
                    sol = max(sol,max(subsets[x].rank,subsets[y].rank));
                    sol = max(sol,subsets[t].rank);
                }
            }
        }
        sol = max(sol,subsets[t].rank);
    }
    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        cin >> q;
        if(q==1)
        {
            cout << sol << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cin >> t;
            t--;
            if(s[t] == '0' && t!=0 && t!=n-1)
            {
                s[t] = '1';
                subsets[t].rank = 1;
                if(s[t-1] == '1')
                {
                    int x = find(subsets,t-1);
                    int y = find(subsets,t);
                    if(x!=y)
                    {

                        Union(subsets,t-1,t);
                        sol = max(sol,max(subsets[x].rank,subsets[y].rank));
                        sol = max(sol,subsets[t].rank);
                    }
                }
                if(s[t+1] == '1')
                {
                    int x = find(subsets,t+1);
                    int y = find(subsets,t);
                    if(x!=y)
                    {

                        Union(subsets,t+1,t);
                        sol = max(sol,max(subsets[x].rank,subsets[y].rank));
                        sol = max(sol,subsets[t].rank); 
                    }
                    //Union(subsets,t+1,t);
                }
            }
            if(s[t] == '0' && t==0 )
            {
                s[t] = '1';
                subsets[t].rank = 1;
                if(s[t+1] == '1')
                {
                    int x = find(subsets,t+1);
                    int y = find(subsets,t);
                    if(x!=y)
                    {
                        Union(subsets,t+1,t);
                        sol = max(sol,max(subsets[x].rank,subsets[y].rank));
                        sol = max(sol,subsets[t].rank);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(s[t] == '0' && t==n-1)
            {
                s[t] = '1';
                subsets[t].rank = 1;
                if(s[t-1] == '1')
                {
                    int x = find(subsets,t-1);
                    int y = find(subsets,t);
                    if(x!=y)
                    {
                        Union(subsets,t-1,t);
                        sol = max(sol,max(subsets[x].rank,subsets[y].rank));
                        sol = max(sol,subsets[t].rank);
                    }
                }
            }
            sol = max(sol,subsets[t].rank);
        }
    }
}
```